# create multiple images view like the photo app iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

How can create a view with mutiple images, something similiar to the photo app on the iphone?

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So  if you want a 4 by 4 grid of pictures (that are 20x20) each for example, you can use a scroll view and add UIImageViews to it something like

```
UIScrollView *s= [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]
int position x=10;
int position y=10;
for(int i=1; i<=pictures.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *image= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,20,20)]
    image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:..] //initialize the image for the view
    [s addSubview:image];
    if(i%4==0) //means you need to start a new row
     {
          y+=20; //you can tweak this to make it look how you like
          x=10; //come back to the beggining
     }
   else
      x+=10; //again tweak this to make it "look" right

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My standard answer: check out the `TTPhotoViewController` in the [Three20 project](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20):

> TTPhotoViewController emulates Apple's
>   Photos app with all of its flick n'
>   pinch delight. You can supply your own
>   "photo sources", which works
>   similiarly to the data sources used by
>   UITableView. Unlike Apple's Photos
>   app, it isn't limited to photos stored
>   locally. Your photos can be loaded
>   from the network, and long lists of
>   photos can be loaded incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

Works better for me (Daniel's code modified) :

```
UIScrollView *s = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
int numOfColumns = 4;
int numOfRows = imagesArray.count/numOfColumns+1;
int space = 10;
int width = (s.frame.size.width-(numOfColumns+1)*space)/numOfColumns;
int height = width;
int x = space;
int y = space;
for (int i=1; i<=imagesArray.count; i++) {
    UIImageView *image= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i-1]];
    [s addSubview:image];
    [image release];
    if (i%numOfColumns == 0) {
        y += space+height;
        x = space;
    } else {
        x+=space+width;
    }
}
int contentWidth = numOfColumns*(space+width)+space;
int contentHeight = numOfRows*(space+height)+space;
[s setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:s];
```

`imagesArray` is an `Array` of `NSData`