# How to populate a UIScrollView with UIImageView's lines up in a row

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I need some code on how to make a `UIScrollView` that contains UIImageViews lined up like the iPhone photo's app that comes with the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a frequently asked question around here.  Several questions that might have answers on the various aspects of doing this are

- [UIScrollView image/photo viewer with paging enabled and zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975708/uiscrollview-image-photo-viewer-with-paging-enabled-and-zooming)
- [Photos app-like gap between pages in UIScrollView with pagingEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849383/photos-app-like-gap-between-pages-in-uiscrollview-with-pagingenabled)
- [Flicking through pages / photos with UIImageViews (similar to Facebook photos app or home screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791977/flicking-through-pages-photos-with-uiimageviews-similar-to-facebook-photos-app)
- [Is it Possible to Center Content in a UIScrollView Like Apple’s Photos App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496015/is-it-possible-to-center-content-in-a-uiscrollview-like-apples-photos-app)
- [create multiple images view like the photo app iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627053/create-multiple-images-view-like-the-photo-app-iphone-sdk)

The Three20 framework has a [drop-in component](http://github.com/joehewitt/three20/blob/master/src/Three20/TTPhotoViewController.h) for doing just this, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is probably a standard `UITableView` whose cells contain a row of four `UIImageView`s. In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, load the four images corresponding to that row (assuming you've got them in a linear array, the image indices would be (row*4), (row*4 + 1), (row*4 + 2), and (row*4 + 3)), and apply them to the cell's image views. Make sure to use `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` or your performance—specifically, the overhead of creating and destroying all the views involved—will be terrible.