# uiview screen fade in and fade out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

so, I created a Single View Application and I have 30 views in my application, all of the views are the same except of a picture in the center of the view and the 'next' and 'back' buttons that will direct the user to the next screen.

my question is, do I need to create 30 views or I just can programmatically to add more views to create the stack? I mean, when the user click 'next', it will create a new view and the user will redirect to this new view with the properties that I will define for the new view?

thanks alot!

Comment: do you have just different 30 views or 30 different screens(viewControllers) ? maybe you can explain a little more

Comment: Where did you learn ios development... Get yourself a good book... Your foundation in ios is very weak

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962658/how-to-populate-a-uiscrollview-with-uiimageviews-lines-up-in-a-row which will allow you to have some animation via a `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, do not create 30 views. Add a single view with a UIImageView and bind it to a view controller property as an IBOutlet. When the user presses the next and back buttons, just update the "image" property of the UIImageView.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I wasent that clear in what in wrote.
so, I have a view, this is the main view, he has a uiimageview and uilabel and 2 uibuttons. when the user click on the 'next' button, I want the screen to fade out and than to fade in with a new image on the uiimageview and with another button and another text on the uilabel. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you would just use animations. Fade out the UIImageView, update the image property, then fade the UIImageView back in. Look up block animations, specifically, the UIView static method animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to create new views. Look in the documentation for the `UIView` class and play around.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go through the below doc to create app thats uses page-by-page presentation.

[PageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html)